# Form mysql read and writeback

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

So im able to read data from db to populate the forms the way i want to.

```
<?php
$dbQuery_custom_toggle = "SELECT * "; 

$dbQuery_custom_toggle .= "FROM custompage"; 
$result_custom_toggle = mysql_query($dbQuery_custom_toggle) or die("Couldn't get file        list");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_custom_toggle)) {
?>
<?php echo $row['np_menu_titel'];?>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="np_menu_active_post" value="" <?php if($row['np_menu_active'] == "1"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?> />  <br />





<?php
 }
 ?>
```

So this will populate the form with all the available rows.
Meaning this will get me as many checkboxes (with name) as there are entry's in the db

The problem im having, how do i return EACH value back to the db?

```
  update custompages SET np_menu_active ='?' ,
```

i have no clue here, any help is appreciated,
i want when the form is submitted, that it sends back 1 to each row corrosponding with the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better make the checkboxes an array.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="np_menu_active_post[]" value="" <?php if($row['np_menu_active'] == "1"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?> />
```

Then post it to wherever you want and process like this.

```
$chekbox_vals = $_POST['np_menu_active_post']; // This will pass the selected checkbox values as an array

if(count($chekbox_vals) > 0) {
     // Loop it and update the values in DB

}
```

Comment: that is ofcourse becuase i set them to 1... i know, how to format the query so it will update only the selected ones?

Comment: So im implementing it, but as said it will turn all checkboxes to 1 http://pastebin.com/35C4hsAu

Answer (score 0):

If your database has an id field you can use AJAX to update database using `onchange()` event

```
<?php echo $row['np_menu_titel'];?>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="np_menu_active_post" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"value="" onchange="doAJAX(<?php echo $row['id'];?>)"<?php if($row['np_menu_active'] == "1"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?> />  <br />
```

Comment: im not into ajax at the moment, as in, i know shit from ajax :)

Comment: @defiancenl Even if you are not using AJAX it would still be advisable to have an id for each checkbox.`id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>`